# window.Map is not a constructor in Google Maps API v3

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I have a google map with a new key

but it gets error in console

error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: window.Map is not a constructor
    at Zr (map.js:2)
    at ds.release (map.js:53)
    at gs (map.js:5)
    at _.rl.Ab (map.js:59)
    at map.js:46
```

HTML

```
<head>
<script async defer
        src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=mykey">
</script>
</head>

<body onload="init()">
    <div id="map_canvas"></div>
</body>
<script src="js/index.js"></script>
```

index.js

```
Map = null;
function init() {
    var mapOptions = {***};
    Map = new google.maps.Map( document.getElementById( "map_canvas" ), mapOptions );
}
```

Thanks for your time!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Map is reserved word in EcmaScript, so you shouldn't use it as a variable name: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map

The problem is this line (jsfiddle thinks `Map` is read only):

```
Map =  null;
```

Rename your map variable to something else (like `map`, with a lower case "m").

[proof of concept fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/geocodezip/6nfuszpr/1/)

**code snippet:**

```js
map = null;

function init() {
  var mapOptions = {
    center: {
      lat: 0,
      lng: 0
    },
    zoom: 1
  };
  map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"), mapOptions);
}
google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, "load", init);
```

```css
html,
body,
#map_canvas {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px
}
```

```html
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js"></script>
<div id="map_canvas"></div>
```

Answer (score 2):

This is a problem with the weekly version of maps this week. I changed:
...//maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key....
to 
...//maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3.34&key...

the first path server the weekly version of maps which is default. 
I chose it to set the version to 3.34 which worked fine. I could have chosen a quarterly version which would update automatically to the version of the current quarter(it would automatically update next quarter) by inserting v=quarterly. Either way the 3.34 fixed my issues.

Comment: Not a real solution. In a year v3.34 will be deprecated and you'll receive the default version https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/versions#choosing-a-version-number