# Uncaught TypeError: window.Map is not a constructor

Tags: google-maps, typeerror

I've got a problem at https://haut-poitou.fr/categories/
Since a few days, i got an error :

```
map.js:2 Uncaught TypeError: window.Map is not a constructor
    at Xr (map.js:2)
    at bs.setZIndex (map.js:54)
    at ds.He (map.js:57)
    at _.pl.Bb (map.js:60)
    at Ot (map.js:44)
    at map.js:45
```

It appears on each page with a map somewhere in it, and repeats, sometimes up to 50 or more errors. The map seems to geolocate somehow, but the background is missing, only pins appear.

I tried to deactivate/reactivate all plugins, wordpress version is updated, with no effect on the issue. 
I found some topics here and there to solve the issue, like here :
[window.Map is not a constructor in Google Maps API v3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53550527/window-map-is-not-a-constructor-in-google-maps-api-v3)
but unfortunately i'm total noob with this and I don't even know where i'm supposed to custom the code.

If anybody could help me with this, it would be so awesome ! 

Thank you

Answer (score 2):

It's caused by a new version of Maps being released.  Fall back to v3.34 for now, but that is not a permanent fix since v.3.34 will be eventually unavailable.  See if you have a variable named "Map" anywhere that you can rename so it doesn't conflict with their "Map".

Answer (score 2):

MrSethT offers a more complete solution.
**Adding the version number back to 3.34 does work**, but as noted it will fail later when 3.34 is retired.

Here is our working script where the variable **map** is changed to **varmap**

```
<script>
// Initialize and add the map
function initMap() {
  // The location of mapTarget
  var mapTarget = {lat: 9.941625, lng: -85.660698};
  // The map, centered at mapTarget
  var varmap = new google.maps.Map(
      document.getElementById('map'), {zoom: 16, center: mapTarget});

  var contentString = 
      '<h3 id="firstHeading" class="firstHeading">Le Cabanon</h3>'+
      'W8RQ+JP Playa Guiones,<br />Guanacaste Province, Costa Rica';

  var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
    content: contentString
  });

  var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    position: mapTarget,
    map: varmap,
    animation: google.maps.Animation.DROP,
    title: 'Le Cabanon'
  });
  marker.addListener('click', function() {
    infowindow.open(map, marker);
  });
}
 </script>
```

Comment: So if I understand correctly, there was a clash with the `Map` variable name? I had a `Map` Object in my codebase, and changed it to `MyMap` and suddenly it started working again. Thanks!